# What is the steady state for this difference equation: $X_{n+1}-X_{n}+\beta \alpha X_{n-1}(1-\frac {X_{n-1}}{X_{max}})=t$

Tags: recurrence-relations

This is my self study, as I know the steady state from an difference equation should satisfy $x=X_{n+1}=X_{n}$

What is the steady state for this difference equation?

> $$X_{n+1}-X_{n}+\beta \alpha X_{n-1}\left(1-\frac {X_{n-1}}{X_{\max}}\right)=t$$  $\beta$, $\alpha>0$ $~t$ is constant, so this equation look like non-homogenous.

I confused while I was trying to derive $X_{\max}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Steady state, if it exists, should satisfy:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} X_n = x \in \mathbb{R}$$
Hence, we have
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(X_{n+1}-X_{n}+\beta \alpha X_{n-1}\left(1-\frac {X_{n-1}}{X_{max}}\right) \right)=t$$
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} X_{n+1}- \lim_{n \to \infty} X_{n}+\beta \alpha \lim_{n \to \infty} X_{n-1}\left(1-\frac {\lim_{n \to \infty} X_{n-1}}{X_{max}}\right)=t$$
$$x -x + \beta \alpha x(1-x/x_{\max}) = t \implies \beta \alpha x(1-x/x_{\max}) = t$$
Solve the quadratic to obtain $x$.

Comment: how about $X_{max}$?

Comment: @valerie $X_{max}$ is a known quantity. You do not solve for $X_{\text{max}}$

Comment: do you mean like this $\beta \alpha x - \beta \alpha x^2- t=0 $

Comment: @valerie. Please look at the last equation given by user17762. It contains Xmax which is known and part of the quadratic.

Comment: ahhh, I see...okay many thanks all. I just recognize the $X_{max}$ which is also constant known..